# iPad Retina display only using 1024 for webpages

Tags: asp.net, ios, ipad, web

I have a bit of an issue, I am developing a full HD (1920x1080) website which I also want to be able to use on the iPad retina display (2048x1536) however the iPad is only showing that it has a resolution of (1024x768) despite the specs clearly stating otherwise (http://www.apple.com/uk/ipad/specs/)

If I create a div of width 1024 then it appears full screen on the iPad and a div of 1920 width forces the iPad to scroll?

Does anyone know why I cannot use the full retina display and am forced to 1024x768 resolution on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intended behaviour.

Since most web sites still specify their text size in pixels (12px), a retina screen would results in text that is much too small. To avoid this, Safari on the iPad 3rd gen and iPhone 4/4s tell web servers that they have 1/4 the resolution they really have. The text is then rendered in finer details by Safari but it also retains its intended size.

As a workaround, try setting the meta tag "viewport" in your site to allow for a greater resolution.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there no way a developer can override this behaviour?

Comment: Update answer on how to override the behaviour... :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, your answer seems to have pointed me on the right track, using the following seems to work however would there be any reason not to use this? : <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=0.5,minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=0.5">

Comment: That setting just alters the zoom level of your pages, if your page natively supports the retina resolution it's best to use '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />' [Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Set your initial viewport size to half of it's original size thus creating a canvas that is double the size that the hardware returns (1024px * 2 = 2048px).