# Why is iPad window width read as 1024?

Tags: jquery, ipad

The display specs for an iPad Air 2 are 2048 x 1536 but when a loaded page does a

```
$( window ).width()
```

to get the viewport width it comes back as 1024.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a [viewport specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)? I think that *may* make a difference. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915530/ipad-retina-display-only-using-1024-for-webpages?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel screen size != pixel screen resolution.

Older iPads have a pixel density of 132 PPI, and newer ones have 264 PPI.

The physical pixel size of the window is in fact 1024, but is scaled up because of the increased PPI to 2048.